# Extract Year from Date and insert into new field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I know I can extract the Year of my ordered_date field with

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(ordered_date, "%Y-%m%d")) from wccrm_orders
```

I tried with

```
insert into wccrm_orders (year) values
(SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(ordered_date, "%Y-%m%d")) from wccrm_orders)
```

But it just adds empty entries after the last id...

How can I insert the result into a new field "year"?

Thank you for any help.

BR, Stefan

Comment: try it without `values`

Comment: And remove the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for an `update`?

```
update wccrm_orders
    set year = year(str_to_date(ordered_date, '%Y-%m%d'));
```

Based on the logic, you might also be able to do:

```
update wccrm_orders
    set year = left(ordered_date, 4) + 0;
```

It is not clear why you would want to store the date separately from the `ordered_date`.  Simply store the date as a `date` or `datetime`.  Then you can calculate the year whenever you need it.

Comment: Dear Gordon, thank you - you were absolutely right. No insert, just an update! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
insert into wccrm_orders (year) values(SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(ordered_date)) from wccrm_orders)
```

If not, try:

```
insert into wccrm_orders (year) values(SELECT YEAR(ordered_date) from wccrm_orders)
```

Comment: Dear Rafiul, thank you for your time. An update solved the issue! BR, Stefan